# Twitter REST API : "Invalid or expired token"

Tags: php, twitter

```
<?
include_once("$SrvRoot/library/lib_base.php");
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('../config/twconfig.php');


// I defined YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET,
YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN, YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET in twconfig.php
$connection = new TwitterOAuth("YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET",
"YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");

$param = array( 'q' => 'mytweetttt' );

$tw_data = $connection->get('search/tweets', $param);

Util::dumpArray($tw_data); // It's same with echo "<pre>"; var_dump($tw_data); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

I coded like this, but I got "Invalid or expired token" message.
When I tested using OAuth tools using cURL command on linux server, There's working.

Why TwitterOauth shows that message? Please give me advice what's the problem.

Comment: I believe that the Error is self explainatory, dude, its says "Invalid or expired token", youre token is either "Invalid" OR "Expired" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you pass **strings** instead of variables/constants?

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth("YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET",
"YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
```

If you defined constants it should be:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET,
YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN, YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's my mistake. But, now I got "Could not authenticate you" message. Do you help me, once again?

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with your KEYS, check once again if your keys are correct and if you pass them in the correct order.

Comment: Oh. I input values instead of defined constants, then working. :D Thanks for your advice. Have a nice day!